# Getting NameError: undefined method `start' for class `#<Class:0x000056251f39f6a8>'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, simplecov

Added below configuration in spec_helper.rb on top of file.

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start 'rails'
```

I am trying to generate the specs coverage report using SimpleCov. Installed simplecov gem too.

Rails version is 5. Still not able to generate coverage folder.

Comment: `specs_helper.rb` is not a file that rspec uses (by default, anyway). Did you mean `spec_helper` or `rails_helper`?

Comment: yeah, it is spec_helper.rb file.

Comment: It would be great if you could confirm the test framework you are using and please make sure that SimpleCov starts before the application code gets loaded.

Comment: I am using Rspec as test framework, SimpleCov is not getting started when I try to load in on console.